# Working with the MSGEQ7 clock input

Tags: capacitor, resistors

I just got a MSGEQ7 equalizer chip. I have everything wired up like http://nuewire.com/info-archive/msgeq7-by-j-skoba/ except for the 33pF cap. I have no idea where to even find those. I think somehow the cap and resistor work together to control the clock and I have no idea how that works. The chip gives expect values when I hold the wire, but when I plug the wire into 200kohms and my series of 3 10pF caps, it does nothing. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 33pF cap is needed to make the on chip RC (resistor capacitor) oscillator work. If you leave it out then there will be no clock for the chip.
Putting 3 10pF caps in series will actually produce 3.3pF, (which may be too low for the oscillator to work properly) as capacitors work the opposite way to resistors in this regard. If you put them in parallel you will gt 30pF and it should work.

Although the [datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/MSGEQ7.pdf) gives little info about the recommended values a formula or any graphs, it should work with slightly lower/higher values of capacitor (e.g. 20-200pF) but the internal clock will be faster/slower. Changing the 200k resistor will make a difference too, frequency will be proportional to 1/RC.

Here is some info on RC based oscillators:

[Relaxation oscillator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relaxation_oscillator)

[CMOS oscillators](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/an/AN/AN-118.pdf)

[RC oscillator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_oscillator)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you happen to have any reads for how the cap and resistor work together to make the oscillator go a certain speed? I don't even know what that's called!

Comment: @Kyle - I added a couple of links, you can find more by using the names in Google. The relaxation type oscillator is the one usually used in digital circuits as it produces a square wave (can be used to produce a triangle wave with a constant current source too)

Comment: The CMOS pdf describes various digital gate based oscillators probably similar to the one used in your chip and many other ICs. The last one describes sine wave oscillator like the Wien bridge and twin T, well worth knowing about and understanding too. The general theory of an RC filter and it's uses will be discussed in any decent electronics book (e.g. Art of electronics, Practical electronics for Inventors) Hope this helps a bit.